# Number of active sockets on a port?

Tags: python, sockets

```
>>import socket
>>s=socket.socket() //creates a TCP socket of address family; internet appications IPv4
>>s.bind(("0.0.0.0",8888))
>>s.listen(2)
>>client,addr=s.accept()
```

How can I find out the number of IPs trying to connect to the socket I created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the `netstat` command to check the network connections. Can't find a way to do this in pure python code.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    c.send('Thank you for your connecting')
    c.close()
```

this will indicate the connections initiated!

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a counter and it will be incremented by one, on every connection received.

```
    connectionCounter = 0
    while True:
        connectionCounter += 1
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connection number: ' + str(connectionCounter)
        c.send('Thank you for your connecting')
        c.close()
```

I am adding a video link below to demonstrate the same. I hope it helps.

[Demonstration of the above code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGtGJSMr7vU&feature=youtu.be)

By using curl I am making connection request to the server.